# Samba 4.3 does not perform file modification as the configured user

Tags: samba

This is an issue that began with Ubuntu 14.04's pushing everyone from samba 4.1 to 4.3 last month (which was an unusually ballsy move for Ubuntu to do to an LTS release, and is causing [all kinds of problems](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bugs?field.searchtext=4.3.8&orderby=-datecreated&search=Search&field.status%3Alist=NEW&field.status%3Alist=OPINION&field.status%3Alist=INVALID&field.status%3Alist=WONTFIX&field.status%3Alist=EXPIRED&field.status%3Alist=CONFIRMED&field.status%3Alist=TRIAGED&field.status%3Alist=INPROGRESS&field.status%3Alist=FIXCOMMITTED&field.status%3Alist=FIXRELEASED&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status%3Alist=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&assignee_option=any&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.bug_commenter=&field.subscriber=&field.tag=&field.tags_combinator=ANY&field.status_upstream-empty-marker=1&field.upstream_target=samba&field.has_cve.used=&field.omit_dupes.used=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.affects_me.used=&field.has_patch.used=&field.has_branches.used=&field.has_branches=on&field.has_no_branches.used=&field.has_no_branches=on&field.has_blueprints.used=&field.has_blueprints=on&field.has_no_blueprints.used=&field.has_no_blueprints=on) for folks, but I digress.) I assume there must be some different configuration in the 4.3 series that will meet my modest needs, so asking here.

I have a simple configuration intended to allow pretty wide open file sharing. Complete config is below, but the idea is to allow guests, perform all file activity as user mbaynton on the server, and force files and directories created by samba to be mode 0744. This worked as desired until 4.3 - in particular, one could create a new file or directory through samba and subsequently modify it through samba.

The behavior I now see is that a new file or directory created by samba will have the expected mode -- 0744, so owner rwx, will be owned by the mbaynton user and mbaynton's primary group as before, **but** attempts to modify any existing file or directory through samba, including new ones created with samba, fail with permission denied.

If I add group write permission to a particular file, it can then be modified by samba, but this shouldn't be necessary as samba should be performing the write as mbaynton. Changing all files I want accessible by samba to be g+w isn't really a solution.

How do I update my samba 4.1 configuration to successfully perform basic file sharing in 4.3?

smb.conf:

```
[global]
    workgroup = home
    server string = NAS
    netbios name = nas
    interfaces = lo eth0
    hosts allow = 127. 192.168.123. 192.168.124.
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 10000
    security = user
    map to guest = Bad User
    guest account = mbaynton
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    local master = yes

[data]
    comment = Root of zpool
    writable = yes
    path = /data
    force user = mbaynton
    guest ok = yes
    public = yes
    force create mode = 0744
    force directory mode = 0744
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is nothing wrong with Your config. Check whether user account for "mbaynton" exists in smbpasswd database.

I can not explain why this is not needed for creating new files while for saving it is. Some kind of inconsistency in samba logic :)

ArturrO